# SplitViewController query

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

In an Universal Application, what happens if I use platform specific features like Popover, SplitViewController for iPad, without checking the device using

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

method. Will the Application crash if it is running in iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried creating a little dummy project, dragging everything together and running it?

Comment: It will not crash, but when using popOver in iphone once I got debug log saying you cannot user popOver in iPhone.

Comment: No, currently I have a Windows machine. Couldnt able to check the same now. When I was doing a study, I am raised with this doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question: yes, it will. Specific controllers only work in specific environments (who would have guessed...) You can also avoid that kind of code `if(IS_iPAD()){//Do something}`.

The error it would produce:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
```